# How can I create template class member implementations in the cpp file for multiple types

Tags: c++, templates

I've got a template class called w32file which works with both wchar_t and char.  It's declared:

```
template <typename T>
    class w32file { ... }
```

And it has many member methods such as this one:

```
inline bool isDirectory();
```

Now I know I could put all the implementation of these member methods in the header file and they'd then get compiled in to whatever object files use my template.  However, I don't really want this since this class is going to get used all over the place and it's going to lead to alot of repeated object code.

So at the moment, I have a cpp file which is linked to a static lib which does this:

```
bool w32utils::w32file<wchar_t>::isDirectory()
{
    auto dwAttr = GetFileAttributes(m_name.c_str());
    return ((dwAttr & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY);
}

bool w32utils::w32file<char>::isDirectory()
{
    auto dwAttr = GetFileAttributes(m_name.c_str());
    return ((dwAttr & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY);
}
```

Now, my object code only get's created once, but I've had to create two copies of essentially the same method in my source code.  Does anyone know a way around this?  Is there a way to get both implementations expanded into my object file in a templated way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the function templated and use explicit template instantiation:

```
namespace w32utils
{
  template <typename T>
  bool w32file<T>::isDirectory()
  {
    const auto dwAttr = GetFileAttributes(m_name.c_str());
    return ((dwAttr & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY);
  }


  template class w32file<char>;
  template class w32file<wchar_t>;
}
```

Note that I would strongly recommend putting that in the header and **inlining** it!

Comment: Hmm, so will this somehow avoid the object code getting created multiple times?  You see with my annoying copy/paste method I could at least have the object code in just one dll.  Won't this result in the object code being in every dll which happens to use a w32file?

Comment: I was assuming that you put this into a .cpp file and keep the header free of definitions. Then the code should be generated just in that one translation unit. The downside is that you cannot use the class for any types that you didn't instantiate, because the compiler won't even know the definitions. (But please do note my remark about inlining. This almost direct function forwards is begging to be inlined.)

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, I'll give this a try now.  And yes I take your point about inlining.  My original method actually had the functions inlined too.

Comment: Also do add `const` wherever you can - it'll allow the compiler to make more optimizations, and it might actually be necessary for correctness. Your `isDirectory` method should be `const` for sure.

Comment: @Itjax: (Sorry, I meant `const auto`, NOT `const auto &`, that was broken.) I wasn't referring to function arguments, though, but to the local `dwAttr`. By making it const, the compiler knows that it can try to remove the variable entirely. Sure, it might also figure this out from a non-const variable, but why be imprecise if what you have really *is* a constant within your scope?

Comment: Indeed `const` is more of a correctness tool rather than an optimization tool. Therefore, use it by default. It makes the code easier to read and reason about (imagine in 4 years you look up the declaration of something, and then see it's const; you instantly know that that value is not mutated anywhere)

Comment: whether there is optimization or not, I'd suggest `inline bool isDirectory() const;` as otherwise a `const w32file<char> tempFile = ...;` wouldn't have access to isDirectory(), would it?

Comment: @Tim: Are you sure `inline` is OK for this situation where I need the TU to link against other, separately compiled objects?

Comment: Hm I didn't think about whether inline would be okay or not, I just copied Benj's line and wanted to stress out the `const` at the end of the declaration. I unfortunately can't tell if inline works that way for templates, maybe someone else can.